# How should I use correctly the sync modifier with vuetify input custom event `@update:error`?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify, more specifically the [`v-text-field` component](https://dev.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields).

This component has a custom event `@update:error` that is syncable. I want to use it to update a boolean field in my template data object, and use this field to update an appended icon.

I have read [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) and assumed it should work in the code below, but it doesn't; and I don't know what I missed. Here is a minimal example:

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-row>
      <v-col xs="8" col="8" xl="6" offset-xl="3">
        <v-form>
          <v-text-field v-model.trim="newUser.firstname" 
                        :rules="nameRules" 
                        label="Firstname" 
                        :append-icon="errors.firstname ? 'mdi-alert-circle-outline' : 'mdi-check'"
                        :error.sync="errors.firstname">
           </v-text-field>
        </v-form>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

The error event does not update my `errors.firstname` field consistently, thus not updating the appended icon.

Check it in this pen: https://codepen.io/billybobbonnet/pen/RwNRmqd?editors=1011

How can I get my data field to update with the synced event? If this event is somehow broken, is there a workaround you would advise me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is sort of broken. I'm not really sure what was design intend but it feels really strange now.

Documentation of the prop clearly states `error: Puts the input in a manual error state`.

Lets look at the [implementation](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/validatable/index.ts)

1. It is clear component [should always report as invalid](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/validatable/index.ts#L83) when this prop is set to `true`. OK
2. `update:error` event with value of `true` is send when some of the `rules` are broken. Doesn't make sense at all. If prop is intended for user to set error state manually, why firing `update` event as a result of validation ?
3. If you fix issue with field, `update:error` with value `false` is not send because it's blocked by `error` prop with value `true`. wtf?

So using `error.sync` absolutely doesn't make sense. It's an error in documentation at best. Bad design if you ask me. There should be some other event, with different name dedicated for communicating the validation state of the field...

### How to go around it - take 1

One way would be to not pass `error` prop to field at all and just use the event:

```html
<v-text-field @update:error="errors.firstname = $event">
```

Works but there is still one problem tho. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7876). When the field is rendered, it's also validated but no error is shown and no `update:error` is send. When you focus field and leave it without the change, error is displayed but event is **not send** because there was effectively no change in error state (field was in error state before it got focus). One way around it would be to set initial value if your `errors.firstname: true` (because initial value is not valid). Works in this simple example but I would not go that way - it just doesn't scale in real world scenarios (where fields has non empty initial values for example)

### How to go around it - take 2

Best way would by probably to go to Vuetify Github and ask for a feature - convert VInput slots to scoped slots and allow access to validation state inside them. Then you can replace default icon with icon generated from slot.

Until then only option is to use `refs`

```html
<v-text-field v-model.trim="newUser.firstname" 
                        :rules="nameRules" 
                        label="Firstname" 
                        :append-icon="firstnameIcon()" 
                        ref="firstname">
           </v-text-field>
```

```js
methods: {
    firstnameIcon() {
      return this.$refs.firstname && this.$refs.firstname.valid ? 'mdi-check' : 'mdi-alert-circle-outline'
    }
  }
```